# Rule of inference and truth table issue

Tags: logic

Let

P – Light is on

Q – The switch is down

R – The door is open

```
If the switch is down then the light is on.
If the switch is not down then the door is open.
If the door is open then the light is on.
```

Therefore the light is on;

Prove or disprove the argument using,
    i.  Rule of inference
    ii. Truth table

\ My answer .....

\ Rule of inference

```
A. Q⇒P
B. ~Q⇒R
C. R⇒P

D. ~Q⇒P [By {B} and {C}]
E. P [By {A} and {D}]
```

[image: Truth Table]

Which is different from the answer I get from the rule of inference. Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry about the truth table image. I can't upload images till I reach 5 rep points. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your table is correct.   You may be interpreting the result wrong.   You wish to have $P$ true *whenever* the statements $Q\to P, \neg Q\to R,$ and $R\to P$ are *all* true at the same time.   That happens on the last three rows, and $P$ is true for each one.
$$Q\to P, \neg Q\to R, R\to P \;\vdash\; P$$

---

PS: Your application of rules of inference is okay too.    You used hyperthetical syllogism and disjunctive elimination.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean that the whole "P" row doesn't need to be identical to the row we get after  Q→P (and) ¬Q→R (and) R→P ?? Because in the truth table there is a 0 in the 5th line where it is 1 in the "P" row :(

Comment: @Blogger That's it. The last column does *not* have to be *exactly* the same as $P$, you only need $1$ in the first column *whenever* there is a $1$ in the last column.  You only wish to prove a claim about the state of $P$ whenever the three premises all hold; you don't care at all what its state is otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your truth table supports the result of the proof: indeed, in all rows where all the premises are true, the conclusion is also true.

Perhaps you're mixing the situation up with one where you try to prove that $P$ is a tautology?

Comment: So the answer is "P is the correct conclution" right? :) Even in the truth table, if I get the product of 1 and 4 other than getting the product of 1, 2 and 3; Result is the same as the "P" colomn. So can we conclude that "P" is a valid conclusion from the premises given?

Comment: @Blogger The last column does *not* have to be *exactly* the same as $P$, you only need $1$ in the first column *whenever* there is a $1$ in the last column.  You are only proving a claim about the state of $P$ whenever the three premises all hold; you don't care at all what its state is otherwise.

Comment: So it is like; IF " Q→P (and) ¬Q→R (and) R→P = 1" THEN "P = 1"?

Comment: @Blogger It's exactly like that.

Comment: Hey thanks alot @GrahamKemp Now I get it. I thought both the rows should be always identical. Thanks again you saved my day! :D